# Looking for ways to simplify my code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble adding another function in that macro I used to activate or deactivate columns in a Excel Workbook we are using at work. I'm getting the Out of stack space error when running it just adding one of the following function.

Mostly, I've used an If( ***;1;0) to manage the activation part and an If(***;TRUE;FALSE) for the locked/unlocked part. The function I want to had is based on the same idea using a verification code to Clearcontents of a cell and locked it. If the verification code is false, then, I want the cell to be unlocked so the user can write the value. Here is the code line I want to had times 15 as already done for the locked, unlocked function.

```
If Range("AS16") = "Vrai" Then
Range("AA16").ClearContents
Range("AA16").Locked = True
Else:
Range("AA16").Locked = False
End If
```

Here is the code I'm using right now.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("Francis")
Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = ActiveCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cellule In Range("S50:X50")
If cellule.Value = "1" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("S50:X50")
If cellule.Value = "0" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("I50:J50")
If cellule.Value = "1" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("I50:J50")
If cellule.Value = "0" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next cellule

If Range("AR16") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K16").Locked = False
Range("O16").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K16").Locked = True
Range("O16").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR18") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K18").Locked = False
Range("O18").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K18").Locked = True
Range("O18").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR20") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K20").Locked = False
Range("O20").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K20").Locked = True
Range("O20").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR22") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K22").Locked = False
Range("O22").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K22").Locked = True
Range("O22").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR24") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K24").Locked = False
Range("O24").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K24").Locked = True
Range("O24").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR26") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K26").Locked = False
Range("O26").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K26").Locked = True
Range("O26").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR28") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K28").Locked = False
Range("O28").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K28").Locked = True
Range("O28").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR30") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K30").Locked = False
Range("O30").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K30").Locked = True
Range("O30").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR32") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K32").Locked = False
Range("O32").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K32").Locked = True
Range("O32").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR34") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K34").Locked = False
Range("O34").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K34").Locked = True
Range("O34").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR36") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K36").Locked = False
Range("O36").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K36").Locked = True
Range("O36").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR38") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K38").Locked = False
Range("O38").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K38").Locked = True
Range("O38").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR40") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K40").Locked = False
Range("O40").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K40").Locked = True
Range("O40").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR42") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K42").Locked = False
Range("O42").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K42").Locked = True
Range("O42").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR44") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K44").Locked = False
Range("O44").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K44").Locked = True
Range("O44").Locked = True
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Goto Cell

'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Francis"
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Just do a loop with the range where you also have `Step 2`. See [this page](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/step-keyword.html) for example.

Comment: paul bica handed you exactly what you wanted on a silver platter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section can be simplified:

```
For Each cellule In Range("S50:X50")
If cellule.Value = "1" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("S50:X50")
If cellule.Value = "0" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("I50:J50")
If cellule.Value = "1" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Next cellule

For Each cellule In Range("I50:J50")
If cellule.Value = "0" Then cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next cellule
```

To the following (however, note that this will unhide *any* non-zero values).

```
For Each cellule in Range("S50:X50")
    cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = (cellule.Value = "0")
Next
For Each cellule in Range("I50:J50")
    cellule.EntireColumn.Hidden = (cellule.Value = "0")
Next
```

And this section:

```
If Range("AR16") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K16").Locked = False
Range("O16").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K16").Locked = True
Range("O16").Locked = True
End If

If Range("AR18") = "Vrai" Then
Range("K18").Locked = False
Range("O18").Locked = False
Else:
Range("K18").Locked = True
Range("O18").Locked = True
End If

....
```

Can be simplified using a loop over `Range("AR16:AR44")`

```
For Each cellule in Range("AR16:AR44") Step 2
    cellule.Offset(,-33).Locked = (cellule.Value = "Vrai")
    cellule.Offset(,-29).Locked = (cellule.Value = "Vrai")
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

You typically don't want to have performance-expensive code running in that specific handler. `Worksheet_Change` gets invoked *every time a cell changes*... and that includes changing a cell's `Locked` property value.

So that's how you run *out of stack space*: your handler is modifying cells' `Locked` state, which triggers the `Worksheet_Change` event, which modifies cells' `Locked` state, which triggers the `Worksheet_Change` event, which modifies cells' `Locked` state, which triggers the `Worksheet_Change` event, which... which eventually blows the call stack.

So prevent this accidental recursion, you need to prevent Excel from firing worksheet events when you're handling one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'do stuff
CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    'handle errors here...
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

As for simplifying the code, that's more of a mandate for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), once your code works as intended.

> If any C# dev is reading this, this particular situation now has an up-for-grabs issue on Rubberduck's GitHub repository: [#3109 Prevent accidental recursion in Worksheet_Change and Workbook_SheetChange handlers](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/3109); once that inspection is implemented, [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) will be able to warn you when you handle `Worksheet_Change` without disabling application events.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for helping me with that one. I'm sure my boss would thank you aniway. His face turned red when I told him I wasn't able doing it! Looks like the application.enableevents save the day! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The Out of stack error is caused by the Change event, as noted by @Mat

Try this version which also turns the events off and on

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cellule As Range, r As Long, isVrai As Boolean

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Francis"
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    For Each cellule In Union(Range("I50:J50"), Range("S50:X50"))
        With cellule
            Select Case .Value2
                Case "1": .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Case "0": .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End Select
        End With
    Next
    For r = 16 To 44 Step 2
        isVrai = (Range("AR" & r).Value2 = "Vrai")
        Range("K" & r).Locked = Not isVrai
        Range("O" & r).Locked = Not isVrai
        If isVrai Then Range("AR" & r).ClearContents
    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Francis"
End Sub
```